Qgis2web hyperlink on polygon
I would like to create an interactive webmap with the function that each point, line, and polygon, when clicked, will be redirected to a specific URL website. Is there any way I can do that in qgis2web (either by the plugin itself or how to code it in)

Add a field to the attribute table with the links in it. It can be a virtual field so you don't permanently modify the source data.  When you open the exported web map and click on a feature, you'll get a popup with a clickable link.

I did that. But what I need to do is to make the feature itself the clickable link.

If outputting openlayers, here's a working example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68619378/737471

This is what I need. Thank you very much
